# getting a percentage grouped by a column in R

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

```
isYes  sum
  1     5
  0     2
  1     2
```

I want to get the percentage that each sum is Yes

for the above example I would want to output:

```
sum  perc
 2    .5
 5     1
```

How can I do this?

I tried doing something a long the lines of this:

```
df %>% group_by(sum) %>% mutate(perc = ???)
```

Comment: Maybe try: `aggregate(isYes~sum, x, mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need just a mean of `isYes` for each `sum`? If that's correct, you can simply use:

```
df %>% group_by(sum) %>% summarise(perc = mean(isYes))
```

(It should be the same as `df %>% group_by(sum) %>% summarise(perc = sum(isYes)/n())`.)

The result is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    sum  perc
  <int> <dbl>
1     2   0.5
2     5   1
```